# how to access delegate methods in jsf bean

Tags: spring, jsf, jdbctemplate

I am new to jsf and spring concepts.
I have a xhtml page which access custom methods in bean class.
I have used Delegate(Service class) and Dao class.
My question is from the bean class should I call the delegate interface method or the delegate implementation method?

The project structure is as follows:

- xhtml pages
- bean abstract class
- bean implementation class(extended from bean abstract class)
- delegate interface class
- delegate implementation class
- dao interface class
- dao implementation class

Comment: Posting relevant fragments  of your code would make the question more understandable, but from what you've written I would say that if you want to call a class because it implements some interface, then in your declarations use the interface. This makes a cleaner design and [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) easier.

Answer (score 1):

> should I call the delegate interface method or the delegate implementation method?

You *could* of course do both, but relying on the interface you avoid *tight coupling* between the objects.

Think of the interface as the general contract and of its concrete implementation as an instance containing all of the details of the contract.

You could imagine a simple case, and that is of a contract service. You could write an interface that enforces all implementations to follow only one method: `getAllContacts`. So your interface would be:

```
public interface ContactBookInterface {
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts ();
}
```

Interface isn't bothered about such details as how data is internally stored, or where does it come from. All these details are present in implementations. You could consider two implementations:

```
public class ContactBookService implements ContactBookInterface {
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;
    ...
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return contactDAO.findAll();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ContactBookMockService implements ContactBookInterface {
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    public ContactBookMockService() {
        contacts = populateMockContacts();
    }
    ...
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Now, from the point of view of the program, you could have the following managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
...
public void ContactsBean {
    private ContactBookInterface cbi;
    ...
}
```

With such design the concrete implementation is not important, and will be handled by dependency injection of the right one. It is vital to note that you're not tying yourself to implementation design with this approach and you could easily substitute your implementation with the new one, as your code is *loosely coupled*.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! this solved my problem....Thanks again and next time will make it a point to add code snippet too,.....

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, you can always accept the answer that helped you most in solving your problem.